# Bleeding brakes after putting on pads

Tags: brakes, bleeding

Had brake fluid cap off on resivor when changing brake pads used c clamp  to press cylinder in got New pads on put tire on NO pedal went to floor do I have to bleed them now

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Bleeding the brakes is not always necessary at this point, but what you do need to do is pump the pedal to push the pistons out so the pads touch the disc - until then you will have no pedal.

Do make sure that you keep the reservoir topped up...